# Using a GIN index in PostgreSQL with a LIKE clause

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm wondering (I know it's stupid, but...) why the first query works in postgreSQL 11 by index scan (using a GIN index), and the second and the third do not.

```sql
select * FROM test_tbl WHERE "TEST_COL" like '%stinge'::text
select * FROM test_tbl WHERE "TEST_COL" like 'string%'::text
select * FROM test_tbl WHERE "TEST_COL" like '%string%'::text
```

Comment: Did you install the extension pg_trgm? And how did you create the index? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.7

Comment: This question exhibits a clear lack of information.

Comment: Look at the query plans, using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Turn track_io_timing on first if possible.